# Is it possible to block URL using manageable switch

Tags: network

I want to block some specific URLs and DNS addresses.
I am thinking if I buy a manageable switch (More specific would be [TLSF1024D](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=tl-sf1024d#fea))
What can I do to block some sites, and specific URLs like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGH7NxSEGtA  , that are not suitable for children.

Comment: Why did you select that switch to do what you seek? I don't see URL filtering as an option.

Comment: Because i can take one. Tell me if there is any other solutions.

Comment: Some devices can, but those devices shouldn't be called "switches", which name implies layer 2 not layer 7.

Comment: @tylerl what type of devices can do it?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem.  What are you actually trying to do?  A question like "How can I block sites and domains on a home network" will get you lots of options.

Comment: Which, BTW, my go-to answer is to configure your router to use a DNS site that gives you this control.  In fact OpenDNS has specific products designed to be configured on a home router that specifically block objectionable content by refusing DNS lookups for objectionable domains

Answer (score 3):

I think the short answer to this question is "no".  Specifically switches work at layer 2. The content and data you're looking to block is at layer 3.  A switch that's "managed" or "smart" typically means the switch can be managed remotely (command line or web UI) and configured to participate in STP, VLAN, flow control and other layer 2 stuff.

All that said current trends are for network hardware manufacturers to pack more and more stuff into the routing hardware.  Some providers may be integrating some layer 3 functionality into their switches but the link you provide looks like a pretty basic switch to me.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is an local Internet filter on your computer, a firewall, a router, or use an DNS filtering service like [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls/), which can block sites for you.

The switch you liked to says it is 'managed' but that means that you can configure it using its own internal website. 'Managed' does not mean that you can manage your URL traffic.

Switches are not what you need to be looking for, and there are free options of the above.

Comment: i am using openDNS for time but it only blocks whole site not specific urls of a site